# How does React useCallback forms the closure with the global variables inside components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, {useEffect, useCallback, useState} from 'react';

let myHistory = [];

export function App(props) {

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false); // This is just to trigger the re-render 
 
  const func = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(myHistory);
  }, [myHistory]);


  func();

  useEffect(() => {
     console.log("UseEffect Executed")
  }, [myHistory]);


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
        myHistory.push(1);
      }}>Add to history</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Take the above component for example, as per my understanding, the function wrapped inside the useCallback hook initially forms a closure with the global **myHistory** array, which has an initial value of [].

Now whenever I click on the Add to history button, I am changing a toggle state ( just to trigger the re-render of the component ), and also pushing to the myHistory array at the same time. Now when it's re-rendering, since the array reference didn't change the useEffect doesn't run the second time, which is perfectly fine I guess, but the same array dependency goes inside the useCallback dependency array too, so on second render, React should not form a new closure with the updated value of the myHistory array, which means that when func() gets executed on the second render, it should still see the old value of the myHistory array which was [], but somehow on the second render it sees the updated value of the myHistory array which is [1]. How does the function wrapped inside got access to the new updated value of the myHistory array, what am I getting wrong about closures and react here?

Comment: _"it should still see the old value of the myHistory array"_ - there is only ever one value/`myHistory` variable created, which is at the top module scope level. When you push to the global array and your component rerenders, the old `func` still refers to the same array that you just pushed into (after all, there isn't a different array reference that it could point to, as there's only one ever being created), so it will log the changed/update value

Comment: @NickParsons Okay, I have another doubt, will the useCallback return a new function reference in this case?

Comment: It'll return an old function reference, not a new one.